# How does replacing a categorical variable with associated numerical attributes change model flexibility?

Tags: politics

Our data consists of 100 observations (people) of 5 variables. One of the variables is the political party each observation has voted for (parties A, B, C etc.)

As an alternative to party names/assigned letters can be a numerical value based on how that party scored  on a 100 point political scale.

For example, 
a vote for  party A is equivalent to a score of  56 on an authoritarian  - libertarian spectrum. This score variable could then be possibly used as a dependent variable in further analysis.

I'm wondering if this is a valid approach and whether this change would give me more possibilities compared to categorical variable approach. For example, I can  make assumptions regarding individuals political spectrum preferences this way.